# How can I use the values_list in Wagtail (django)?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, wagtail

hi  sorry for my **poor** English

Why wagtail search  return **PostgresSearchResult**   after search ?

i want **PageQuerySet**

like Django postgres search backend  because I can not use  values_list after search

i want to get list of page path ( because i want to find pages parents(Category Page) by path )

and i can't use values_list before search because it does not work

i know, i can use Forloop  but this takes about 5 seconds for each run

My code is very simple :

Django Way : **#Work**

```
ProductPage.objects.filter(title__search="phone").values_list('path')
```

Wagtail Way : **#NotWork** :(

```
ProductPage.objects.search(query).values_list('path')
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bit counter intuitive but you need to always put the `search(query)` call last.

Reading the [Search docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13/topics/search/searching.html#searching-querysets), you will see a note:

- The `search()` method will convert your `QuerySet` into an instance
  of one of Wagtail’s `SearchResults` classes (depending on backend).
  This means that you must perform filtering before calling `search()`.

This means that to get a mostly equal set of results you will need to do the following:

```
query = 'phone'
ProductPage.objects.values_list('path').search(query)
```

Note the `search` is the last call. The search will still function as expected, I have also tested a similar situation on my setup.

`values()`, `values_list()`, `filter()` all return QuerySets where as the Wagtail `search()` takes a QuerySet and returns a non-QuerySet object. The actual database [querying only happens when you iterate (or use) a QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-return-new-querysets) so the order of the QuerySet functions do not matter.